# Как перестроить правильно предложение

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как можно переделать предложение: "Будем надеяться, что каждый водитель прислушался к детям и будет еще белее осторожным и внимательным на дороге, чтобы не допустить аварийной ситуации на дороге"?

Comment: А как это связано с детьми - они что-то говорят или пишут?

Comment: Верьясова, Ваши вопросы и ответы регулярно попадают в "посты низкого качества". Эта ситуация вам очков не добавляет, а у проверяющих (в т. ч. у Вашего покорного) вызывает раздражение. Не знаю, чем помочь, я сам не разобрался еще, почему именно к Вам так строга система. Попробуйте хотя бы форматировать их, что ли... И поподробнее проблему описывать.

Comment: Я что во фразе такого, что её нужно переделывать? Тяжеловата немного на слух, но не более.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будем надеяться, что каждый водитель прислушался к мнению детей и будет еще  осторожнее и внимательнее, чтобы не допустить аварийной ситуации на дороге.

Comment: Спасибо за столь быстрые ответы.